# Can't get incoming mail over TLS for Postfix SMTP Relay

Tags: ssl, postfix, smtp

I have a Postfix Ubuntu VM acting as a mail relay server, which accepts mail on port 25 and forwards it on to Microsoft Exchange online for delivery. This has been working fine for months.

Now I need to allow an SMTP client, which must use TLS, to also send e-mails via the relay. I have added the following to my Postfix main.cf:

```
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3, !TLSv1
smtpd_tls_chain_files =
        ${cert_path}/cert.pem,
        ${cert_path}/chain.pem
```

However when I try swaks with the --tls-on-connect flag I get a "Connection refused" on ports 465 and 587. The old non-encrypted port 25 stuff still works. The pem files are generated by Let's Encrypt and the private key counter parts work for encrypting the outgoing mail to Exchange online. I have verified them with:

```
openssl verify -purpose sslserver  -partial_chain -CAfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/<server FQDN>/chain.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/<server FQDN>/cert.pem
```

However, when I attempt to make a TLS connections from a SMTP client this appears in the log:

```
Mar 18 14:41:49 hermes postfix/smtpd[578652]: warning: error loading chain from /etc/letsencrypt/live/<server FQDN>/cert.pem: key not first
Mar 18 14:41:49 hermes postfix/smtpd[578652]: warning: error loading private keys and certificates from: /etc/letsencrypt/live/<server FQDN>/cert.pem,?/etc/letsencrypt/live/<server FQDN>/chain.pem: disabling TLS support
```

I suppose the question I am facing is how to use the Let's Encrypt SSL certificate for enabling TLS on my mail relay server.

Comment: It is not fully clear for me what you are trying. But if you want to test port 25 with TLS use `--tls` and not `--tls-on-connect`.

Answer (score 1):

Both Certbot's `chain` and `cert` files don't contain the server's private key. Both error message are just complaints about that. The key is only contained in the `privkey` file.

If you wish to use a single file with both key and certificates, you need to manually concatenate files (e.g. in a post-hook) and ensure the `privkey` contents goes first, then the `cert`, then the `chain`, in this exact order.

Notice, the `fullchain` file is already a concatenation of `chain` and `cert` in the correct order. Just point to this ready-made certificate file. Also Postfix doesn't need everything to be in a single file; there is specific option to point to the key file.

I use certbot with Postfix like this:

```
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/privkey.pem
```

Comment: Same here, in addition you need to remember to restart postfix when the keys get updated (assuming you do it automatically, which I do). So in my case I have this in /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/example.org.conf:
```post_hook = systemctl restart apache2 postfix dovecot
```

Comment: While this is certainly true, the question originally wasn't about certbot usage details, but about use of certbot-generated files in Postfix.

Comment: And while postfix monitors other files (files in the queue, mapping files etc.) it doesn't monitor the certificate files. Which is why I think my comment is valid.